# Cannot match type of expression using TypeFamilies

Tags: haskell, type-families

I'm trying to understand how does the extension `TypeFamilies` work, but I got bummered when the type system wasn't able to infer the correct type, for an example I considered simple:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text
import Data.String

class AClass t where
  type family AType t :: *
  somefunction :: t -> AType t

instance AClass Text where
  type AType Text = Int
  somefunction = const 4

instance AClass Int where
  type AType Int = Integer
  somefunction = const 3
```

So, I'm asking to associate each instance of `AClass` with an instance of `AType` (or that's what I think I'm asking Haskell to enforce).

Everything seems alright when loading the code into GHCi:

```
$ ghci -X{OverloadedStrings,GADTs} test.hs
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main>
```

The type of `somefunction` is what I declared in the code and some calls to the function get me what I expected:

```
*Main> :t somefunction
somefunction :: AClass t => t -> AType t
*Main> :t somefunction :: Text -> Int
somefunction :: Text -> Int :: Text -> Int
*Main> (somefunction :: Text -> Int) ""
4
*Main> :t somefunction (""::Text)
somefunction (""::Text) :: Int
*Main> somefunction (""::Text)
4
```

But when I try to typecheck the type definition that appears for `somefunction ""` (`(IsString t, AClass t) => AType t`) I get an ugly error from the type checker, even when I'm just copying the type I got from the typechecker!

```
*Main> :t somefunction ""
somefunction "" :: (IsString t, AClass t) => AType t
*Main> :t somefunction "" :: (IsString t, AClass t) => AType t

<interactive>:1:20: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘AType t’
                  with actual type ‘AType t0’
      NB: ‘AType’ is a type function, and may not be injective
      The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for an expression type signature
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      In an expression type signature: (IsString t, AClass t) => AType t
      In the expression:
          somefunction "" :: (IsString t, AClass t) => AType t
```

And no matter what I do, I can't (or don't know) how to force a type that the typechecker could verify and be happy about:

```
*Main> :t somefunction "" :: (t ~ Text, IsString t, AClass t) => AType t

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘AType t0’ with ‘Int’
      Expected type: AType t
        Actual type: AType t0
      The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    • In the expression:
          somefunction "" :: (t ~ Text, IsString t, AClass t) => AType t
*Main> :t somefunction "" :: (t ~ Text, IsString t, AClass t, AType t ~ Int) => AType t

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘AType t0’ with ‘Int’
      Expected type: AType t
        Actual type: AType t0
      The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    • In the expression:
          somefunction "" ::
            (t ~ Text, IsString t, AClass t, AType t ~ Int) => AType t
*Main> somefunction ""

<interactive>:10:1: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘AType t’
                  with actual type ‘AType t0’
      NB: ‘AType’ is a type function, and may not be injective
      The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for the inferred type for ‘it’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall t. (IsString t, AClass t) => AType t
```

So, my questions are, why is the typechecker failing? (has it something to do with something related to completeness by part of the haskell's typechecker?) and how could I fix it, how could I force a type like `:: Int` or `:: (t ~ Int, AClass t, AType t ~ Integer) => AType t` to typecheck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we added

```
instance AClass String where
  type AType String = Int
  somefunction = const 10
```

then what would `somefunction "" :: Int` evaluate to?

One could say that `""` is a `String`, hence `const 10 "" => 10`.
But it could also be that `""` is a `Text`, hence `const 4 "" => 4`.

So, our code is ambiguous, and GHC rightly rejects it. The ambiguity rises from `AType String ~ AType Text ~ Int`: because of this, it is impossible to solve a type equation like `AType t ~ Int` since it has multiple solutions.

GHC is complaining about this injectivity issue in its error:

```
NB: ‘AType’ is a type function, and may not be injective
```

One can fix this by providing the intended `t` to GHC. The easiest way is using an annotation

```
somefunction (""::String)
somefunction (""::Text)
```

A more complex way would be to allow ambiguous types, as suggested by GHC, and then turning on `TypeApplications` as well. We can now write

```
somefunction @ String ""
somefunction @ Text ""
```

(but it seems more complex).

Comment: Ok, the type of `somefunction ""` may be ambiguous and we can tell GHC which type exaclty we mean with an annotation for `'""`, but isn't it possible to annotate `somefunction ""` telling it which type we mean?, something like `(t ~ Text, AType t ~ Int, IsString t, AClass t) => AType t`. (it's interesting that not even `(IsString t, AClass t) => AType t` works, and the typechecker tells me that `AType t` is different of `AType t`, ???)

Comment: Also, where can I find the meaning of injective in this context? I suppose it has to come from type theory somewhere, but I don't know where to search. Could you recomend me some books or papers to look for? thanks

Comment: @helq No, you can't simply annotate the full expression. It's like `show (read "1")` where you compose `String -> a` and `a -> String`, and you need to know what is `a`. Injective is the same as math: when `F x = F y` implies `x=y`, then `F` is injective. Many functions (including type families) are not, since they can map different arguments to the same result.

Comment: thanks, I understand now. It's a little confusing because when I ask GHC for the type of `somefunction ""` I get `(IsString t, AClass t) => AType t` but then GHC fails to typecheck with wathever type I tell it, and I wasn't expecting `AType` to be a function, well gotta learn more. One last question, is it possible to tell GHC that a type function is injective?

Comment: @helq Yes, GHC allows to mark a function as injective, but it _still_ won't help here since GHC will not infer the right constraint -- even if it arguably should. IMO, the current implementation of injective type families is in a sad state: injectivity is checked, some previously ambiguous types become allowed, but the injectivity is not exploited beyond that :-(